# Loop Through Dates and Console.log if Weekend? VBA for Example

Tags: typescript, loops, for-loop

How could I loop through dates in TypeScript and console log the weekends? I have been looking through TS tutorials and am confused when using dates. I know that Sunday = 0 and Saturday = 6 in TS, but I am confused as to which For loop to use. Do I use a for loop for this?

VBA

```
Sub loopWeekends()
Dim eachDay As Date, DayNum As Variant
For eachDay = Date To Date + 90
    DayNum = Application.Weekday(eachDay)
    If DayNum = 1 Or DayNum = 7 Then Debug.Print eachDay
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is a type-strict subset of JavaScript so the answer is roughly the same for both languages.

You can do this by creating a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object then looping through the range you want.

```js
let daysToLoop = 90; //Number of days to check
let offset = 0; //Negative number to start before 4/16/2020
let today = new Date(2020, 4, 16) //Same as just doing new Date() as of 4/16/2020
for(let i = offset; i < daysToLoop; i++) {
    let day = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() + i)
    if(day.getDay() === 0 || day.getDay() === 6) {
        console.log(day) //Weekend Day
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response! I am getting an error for .getYear() saying "Property 'getYear' does not exist on type 'Date'.ts(2339"

Comment: It should be .getFullYear() my bad. I've updated my response.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an array of dates such as

```
let date : Date[] = [date1, date2, date3]
```

You can use a loop similar to this to loop through your dates

```
dates.forEach( (date: Date) => {
    if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6){
        console.log("This is the " + date.getDay() + "th day of the week");
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for the response! I am getting an error saying "Property 'getDay' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)"

Comment: @Ethan oops, my bad. You should call getDay() directly on the Date object and not on  the number returned by getUTCDate(). I've updated my answer.